# Сохранение web страницы в файл

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть страница с некоторыми записям и с check button у каждой записи. После проставления галочек и нажатии на кнопку открывается новая страница, состоящая лишь из отмеченных записей, которую можно сохранить: ПКМ - Сохранить как - page.html. Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку новая страница с отмеченными записями сохранялась автоматически в Page.html?

```
function make_win(mode,par,waiting){

    cmd_str=new Array();
    cmd_str[7]= new Array('Печать_записей',cgi+'?I21DBN='+par[0]+'_PRINT&P21DBN='+par[0]+'&S21FMT='+par[1]+'&S21CNR=555&S21COLORTERMS=0&C21COM=S&S21SRW='+par[2]+'&S21ALL='+par[3]+'&FT_PREFIX='+par[6]+'&SAME_SEARCH='+par[4]+'&FT_REQUEST='+par[5]+'&FT_DISTANCE='+par[7]+'&FT_PARAMS='+par[8]+'&FT_NEAR_MFN'+par[9]);

    x=screen.width-50;
    y=screen.height-50;
    cx=screen.width/2-(x/2);
    cy=screen.height/2-(y/2);

    adr=(waiting) ? '' : cmd_str[mode][1];  

    var load_window = window.open(adr,cmd_str[mode][3],cmd_str[mode][4]+',width='+x+',height='+y+',top='+cy+',left='+cx+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); 

    load_window.focus();
    load_window.onload = function() {

        var html = load_window.document.documentElement.innerHTML; 
        var blob = new Blob([html], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
        window.saveAs(blob, 'print.html');

     };

     if (load_window == null) {
         alert('Отключите блокировку всплывающих окон в своём браузере! Всплывающие окна необходимы для корректной работы сайта!');
     return;
}
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону FileApi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант используйте - [**FileSaver.js**](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```js
function save(argument) {
  var waiting = "ДАННЫЕ";
  
  var html =  '<html><body><div style="position: absolute;width:100%; height:100%; z-index:0;" id="progress_bar" ><table  style="width:100%; height:100%;"><tr><td align=center><div style="background-color: white"><table style="border: 4px double black; background-color: white"><tr><td align=center ><span style="font-size: 11pt; margin:10px; font-weight:bold">Ждите... '+waiting+'</span><br></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></div></body></html>'; 
  
  //var html =  document.documentElement.innerHTML; 
  var blob = new Blob([html], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
  window.saveAs(blob, 'page.html'); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>
   <body> 
      <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      <br/>ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
      <br/>not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
      <br/>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      <br/>publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      <button onclick="save()">Сохранить</button> 
   </body>
</html>
```

### Update 0.0.1(Save url data)

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://cors.io/?https://ru.stackoverflow.com", true); // Для примера
// xhr.open('GET', "ССЫЛКА", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest; 

function processRequest(e) {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { 
  return  xhr.responseText;
 }else{ 
  return  null;
 }
} 

function save(argument) { 
 var html = processRequest(); 
 var blob = new Blob([html], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
  
 window.saveAs(blob, 'page.html'); 
}
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>
   <body> 
      <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      <br/>ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
      <br/>not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
      <br/>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      <br/>publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      <button onclick="save()">Сохранить</button> 
   </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Это то что нужно. Остался один вопрос. Есть некоторое количество записей на странице, условно, 5. Нужные я отмечаю галочками, нажимаю на кнопку, генерируется новая страница, состоящая лишь из отмеченных записей. Вот её и нужно скачать. Как сделать, чтобы она автоматически скачивалась после генерации при нажатии на кнопку "Скачать"?

Comment: Генерируется с помощью функции window.open(*аргументы*). Соответственно, если записать new_window = window.open(), а потом в переменную html: new_window.documentElement.innerHTML, то ничего не работает. Если же кинуть просто new.window, то в файле будет лишь "[object Window]". Как с этим быть?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Речь идёт о работе с БД, штуки вроде "I21DBN" и прочее - аргументы формирующихся ссылок. Собственно, есть записи, которые были выданы по поиску. После того, как отметили нужные, нажимают кнопку, которая создаёт новое окно, в котором лишь нужные, отмеченные записи. А как это окно уже сохранить в документ - уже проблема

Comment: waiting не нужна, по сути, извините, что запутал. Вся страница в cmd_str, строчкой " var load_window=window.open(...", собственно, генерируется. Всё то что ниже, роли не играет

Comment: но конкретно данных у меня нет. Есть адрес, по которому через documentElement.innerHTML взять не получается, есть переменная, в которую записывается windows,open, но через неё не работает. Как взять данные, если есть только адрес генерируемой страницы? Извините за глупые вопросы, достаточно туго идёт с js-ом

Comment: Из базы данных по, собственно, ссылке. Ссылка состоит из ряда параметров вида "I21DBN" и т.д. Грубо говоря - ссылка - это количество, вид и сами записи из бд, а через windows.open() как раз через ссылку создаётся окно с нужными записями

Comment: Но в cmd_str как раз находится ссылка. Если я загоняю в html ссылку, то она не работает. Как мне её распарсить?

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Как мне взять данные страницы по этой ссылке, чтобы запихнуть всё в html?

Comment: Cпасибо большое. Теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой. Если адрес передавать через переменную, то возвращаемый статус - 404. И так, и сяк пробовал, работает, если вручную прописать адрес, через переменную - никак.

Comment: Я для теста вместе return null прописал return url, а то что получилось - вставил вручную, без переменной - и всё работает. А через переменную - никак

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, добавил, как всё это выглядит у меня

Comment: Решил всё таки проблему, через первый способ, всё добавил в вопрос. Не могли бы вы ещё помочь: скачивание файла начинается в старом, а не новом, открывшемся, окне, не знаете как исправить?
P.S. По поводу window.adr. Почему-то просто adr не читал, пришлось явно определять через window.

Comment: @Никита Так и не скажешь, опять же проводите анализ каждой переменой, каждого окна, каждой функции и у вас сразу появятся ясности.